# How much mace to use for a sauce?

Tags: spices

I am making a quart of sauce and want to use just enough mace that it can be detected. How much should I use?

Is there a general set of guidelines of quantities of spices per volume of sauce?

Comment: What kind of sauce?

Comment: What kind of sauce? Different ingredients will mute/enhance different flavors. How much is needed may depend on what *else* is in the sauce.

Comment: Indian or western style sauce?

Comment: In particular, many spices behave very differently if there's a significant amount of fat or dairy. Mace is [a common addition to Béchamel](https://www.bbc.com/food/recipes/bechamelsauce_8751) for example

Answer (score 4):

There are no such guidelines. The needed quantity will be different dependent on all other ingredients in the sauce (both spices and others) but also on the food habits of the eaters.

The way to get it right is to add incremental small amounts and taste.

Comment: Taste taste taste, there's no other way. Mace varies in strength and there's too many variables.